# Using Fan-ID for tourism in Russia without going to the matches

Tags: russia, visa-free-entry, world-cup

If you buy a ticket for a match of *2018 FIFA World Cup Russia*, you get a Fan ID and can use it to enjoy visa-free travel to Russia. Do you have to attend the match as a condition?

I am not a football fan (sorry) but I am tempted to buy a last-minute ticket and use it for a quick Russian tour without going to the stadium. Is this acceptable to the Russian immigration authorities? One obvious downside is losing $210 (or whatever is the cost of the ticket).

I have seen [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95941/can-i-use-a-fifa-fan-id-to-enter-and-leave-russia-for-tourism-purposes) question, although the titles are similar that question has a different situation.

Comment: Would just getting a visa not be cheaper?

Comment: There's quite some paperwork and time involved with that. Plus FAN-ID also has other smaller benefits, like free transport. So that $210 wont be a complete loss.

Comment: Are there geographic limitations on the Fan ID?  My only venture into Russia on a work visa a long time ago effectively restricted me to one city

Comment: I don’t see them listed but I expect there may be some so I will still visit only the cities which are hosting matches.

Comment: Seemingly you need a match ticket in order to use the free travel on trains option (https://www.fan-id.ru/help.html - 21.  If you are traveling on a free train to another city for a match, take your passport, FAN ID in laminated form and match ticket with you – without them you will not be able to board the train.) but it doesn't seem to say anywhere that a ticket is explicitly required in order to use a Fan ID and gain visa-free entry to Russia. It seems that the Fan ID and ticket are treated as separate entities and so actually attending the match doesn't seem to be a requirement.

Comment: @PeterM "A long time ago" as in during or soon after Soviet days? I believe internal travel restrictions in Russia are much less, now.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It was post soviet days, but only a few years afterwards.

Comment: @MrAndySweet it's impossible to upvote a comment; please don't answer a question using a comment, but submit your own answer.

Comment: @CGCampbell I posted it as a comment as it doesn't entirely answer the original poster's question.

Comment: It answers "do you have to attend the match as a condition?"... Since "is this acceptable?" is an opinion question, as the OP doesn't explain acceptable how? or to whom? I believe it actually DOES answer the question, so far as is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fan-ID website has [exerpts from the relevant laws](https://www.fan-id.ru/regulations.html):

> FAN ID is a document for sporting event spectators issued by a federal...
>
> Spectators of sporting events are defined as persons possessing an entrance ticket for a match or a document in a form set forth by the government of the Russian Federation that entitles them to obtain an entrance ticket for a match.

I checked the [law itself](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_147218/b819c620a8c698de35861ad4c9d9696ee0c3ee7a/) (in Russian): it does indeed say that. So technically whether or not you actually attend a match has no bearing on your legal status as a spectator.